# Git, GitHub, VSCode and multiple usernames

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

When using Git and GitHub with VSCode, is there a way to use multiple usernames?

I use the same machine for work and personal. I would like my work projects to be committed using my work username/email and my personal projects to be committed using my personal username/email.

Also, when pushing code to GitHub, VSCode pops up a box at the top asking for my username and password every time. Is there a way to set this once, so that it does not have to be typed in each time?

Comment: Checkout this guide: https://www.micah.soy/posts/setting-up-git-identities/?fbclid=IwAR2jdA2v1xGQRtrTzKNU7Ob_pzE17wgxkewYyEqxrREu7SFNXavRrvqkJLw

Comment: Do you know what version of vscode you are using? It looks like it was an issue with old versions. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26743

Comment: @Raju Latest version of VSCode.